# How to access internal resources from background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

In a Google Chrome application is it possible to access bundled data files from within the `background.js` script?

E.g. if I had a file called `data.json` that I include with the app, is there a JavaScript API that I could use in the `background.js` script to get at the files contents?

With the example bundle directory structure:

```
/app/manfifest.json
/app/backround.js
/app/data.json
```

I want to do something like:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  data = unknown.api.loadFileSync("data.json");
  // do stuff with data
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the API docs you can get the [DirectoryEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryEntry) object for the package directory, and then using the HTML5 FileSystem API get the contents of the file. The API function is [chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry).

```
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function (dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile("data.json", undefined, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                // data now in reader.result                                                        
                console.log(reader.result);
            });
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }, function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer suited better for me. As I'm using manifest version 2 for my app, I couldn't use `"web_accessible_resources"`.

Comment: @Harry you are mistaken. Prior to manifest v2, you could access resources without manifest specification. With v2 and up, you have to specify with [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Answer (score 4):

Background scripts can access resources using `XHR`. To get the URL of the included resource, use `chrome.extension.getURL()`, which returns a fully-qualified URL for the resource.

```
function loadData (file, fn) {
  var dataUrl = chrome.extension.getURL(file),
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function () {
    fn(null, this.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () { fn(this.status); };
  xhr.send();
}


chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  loadData('data.json', function (err, data) {
    // 
  });
});
```

Another approach is to convert the `data.json` file into a `data.js` file and include it as a background script in `manifest.json`. This will let you access any variables set by `data.js`.

**manifest.json**:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["data.js", "background.js"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I found a way to do it without having to use an ajax request. I posted my question too soon!

Answer (score 3):

Since getPackageDirectoryEntry is not supported by firefox, it is not recommended. Now there is a simpler way.

```
async function loadData(resourcePath) {
    var url = chrome.extension.getURL(resourcePath);
    return (await fetch(url)).text();
}
```