# How to read file released with chrome app into blob?

Tags: javascript, blob, google-chrome-app

I have a small file released with my chrome app that I'd like to read into memory.  Everything I've found so far seems to be related to allowing a user to save to their filesystem or choose an file to upload from their [filesystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem).  How can I access this small, internal-to-the-app file that is located at an arbitrary path in my app, e.g.:

`app/resources/myfiles/myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`, as explained by one of the answers to this question: [How to access internal resources from background.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838004/how-to-access-internal-resources-from-background-js).