# List all web accessible resources in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to list all the images I have in a specified folder inside of my chrome extension. However, I think I am fighting web technologies on this one. Is there any env in the chrome extension that executes javascript in a "server" context, as in, could read the files in it's neighboring folders?

Here's what my web accessible resources param looks like:

`"web_accessible_resources": ["*.jpg","*.JPG", "*.png", "*.PNG"]`

I have background script and content script both enabled.

I've tried running an ajax query against the dir to see if it will index but also no luck.

Comment: [How to access internal resources from background.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26838004)

Comment: chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no direct way.

As a workaround you can set up a native app. Get the resources and directories from the manifest file and if there are any wildcards, as in your example, search the directories for them using traditional system calls.

Here's a link to how you can set up the native app and communicate with it using your extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: Thanks, I think then for the amount of juice coming out of the squeeze - I'll just read the web_accesible_resources off of the manifest and inject all my relevant files as part of a prebuild.