# Storing big data for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, database, google-chrome-extension

For my new Chrome extension, I need to store data with about 500,000 records. They will be just a list of existing words, needed only for searching. Theoretically I could put them in JavaScript array, but that's just too many entries, right?

What are the other options that would make sense in this case? How to make this fast and convenient? Is there any client-side solution to prevent API calls?

Comment: IDB? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: A predefined data? Store it in a txt/json file and [read it with fetch/xhr/file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838004/how-to-access-internal-resources-from-background-js)

Comment: read further about browser storage options in the offcial extensions documentation and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @ZigMandel How can I make this question more specific? I said what I need.

Comment: show us what you tried so far and specific coding issues about the storage options in the documentation. read this forum guidelines on how to ask a good question here.

Comment: I'm not asking for code hints, this is purely theoretical question about what is available and recommended. I thought I was very clear with the last paragraph.